# При регистрации ошибка RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile. Django 1.11

Tags: django, python-2.7

После завершения регистрации вылетает ошибка, что у пользователя нет профиля. В админке видно, что user создался, но ни одного профиля нет.. В чём может быть причина?

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    phone = forms.CharField()
    fax = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name', 'phone', 'fax', 'password1', 'password2')
```

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            fax = form.cleaned_data.get('fax')

            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            profile = user.profile
            profile.phone = phone
            profile.fax = fax
            profile.save()
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Телефон')
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Факс', blank=True, null=True)
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

В атрибутах `user` профиль есть. Но когда я пытаюсь посмотреть атрибуты `user.profile` - ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените 
`profile = user.profile` на

```
profile = Profile()
profile.user = user
```

Сигналы нужно убрать

Comment: спасибо большое. мне казалось, тут сигналы нужны)

Comment: Тут, кстати, ещё такой момент. Если, скажем поле username при регистрации мне не нужно... Я убрал его из формы регистрации, но теперь при регистрации мне кидает ошибку Ключ "(username)=(None)" уже существует. И это логично, ведь я унаследовался от класса User. Скажите, как можно присвоить значение для username - айдишник?..

Comment: Так не получится, ТК идшник появляется после сохранения инстанса, но сохранить не получится ТК нет username.

Comment: Тут либо переписывать юзера, либо просто используйте phone для username

Comment: понял спасибо. что нужно, чтобы передать для username емейл, например? profile.username = email?

Comment: 1. добавьте в форму email как обязательное поле 2. в представлении, где сохраняете юзера после  user.is_active = False добавьте user.username = form.cleaned_data['email']

Comment: да, спасибо. так и сделал уже)